# Python: Read Word Document In Order

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-word, docx, paragraph

First time python user here. I'm trying to go through a word document containing both paragraphs and tables. I've figured out how to go through all paragraphs in a document and all tables in a document with the code below:

```
for table in doc.tables:
    for row in table.rows:
        for cell in row.cells:
             print(str(paragraph.text))

for i in doc.paragraphs:
    splitstring = i.text.split(" ", 1)
    print(splitstring[0])
```

But i'm trying to figure out a way to go through the document in order just like anyone reading it would. So if we had a document that contained:

```
Paragraph 1
Paragraph 2
Table 1
Paragraph 3
Table 2
Paragraph 4
```

It would read them in that order. The reason I want to do this is depending on what paragraph a table follows, I want to do different operations on it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you have access to the order information in your code.

In the code you posted you have two loops:
One for printing the content of each table.
One for printing the content of each paragraph.

These loops are executed in sequence, but you would want to intertwine their functionality, something like this:

```
def print_table(table):
    for row in table.rows:
        for cell in row.cells:
            print(str(cell.text))

def print_paragraph(paragraph): 
    splitstring = paragraph.text.split(" ", 1)
    print(splitstring[0])

# Main loop:
for entry in doc.entries: 

   if isinstance(entry, doc.paragraph):
       print_paragraph(entry)
   else:
       print_table(entry)
```

Thus, you need to know if you have any access to the order of the data.
In the hypothetical code above, the data structure `doc.entries` stores the table/paragraph order.

Comment: Hey Max, thanks for the response. Your suggestion makes perfect sense, but i'm getting an error `AttributeError: 'Document' object has no attribute 'entries'`. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Bob, my code was hypothetical, doc.entries was a name that I made up. I don't know if you have access to an attribute that contains both paragraphs and tables in the order that they appear. You need to discover this. Where does your `doc` variable come from? Is it from a Python library? Maybe then there is documentation online. 
If you don't have access to the source of the `doc` variable, try print(dir(doc)). This will show you all attributes and methods that the doc variable has.